# Определение нажатия специальных клавиш CTRL, SHIFT и ALT при клике мышкой в JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Как с помощью JavaScript на веб-странице сообщать в окне

Comment: Я бы посмотрел в сторону KeyboardEvent.getModifierState(). Извините, что не очень подробно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В современных браузерах отлов нажатия специальных клавиш делается следующим образом:

```js
document.addEventListener("mousedown", function(event) {
  var result = "";
  if (event.ctrlKey) {
    result += 'ctrl + ';
  } 
  if (event.altKey) {
    result += 'alt + ';
  }
  if (event.shiftKey) {
    result += 'shift + ';
  }
  switch (event.which) {
    case 1:
      result += 'left mouse';
      break;
    case 2:
      result += 'middle mouse';
      break;
    case 3:
      result += 'right mouse';
      break;
    default:
      result += 'undefined mouse';
      break;
  }
  console.log(result);
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
Зажмите клавиши ctrl, alt и/или shift и кликните мышкой в любое место.
```